# scrapy scrape html source code

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl and scrape a website. I need the whole html instead of components. We can easily extract the component using xpath selectors but is there any method to extract the whole html block for a given class. For example in the below html code, i need the exact html source code of the whole div block prod-basic-info.  Is there anyway i can do this ?

```
<div class="block prod-basic-info">
 <h2>Product information</h2>
 <p class="product-info-label">Category</p>
  <p>
   <a href="xyz.html"</a>
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just point your `xpath` expression or `CSS` selector to the element and [`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) it:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "prod-basic-info")]').extract()[0]
response.css('div.prod-basic-info').extract()[0]
```